# Errors while using Immutable.Map

Tags: typescript, angular5, immutable.js

Getting Error

> Argument of type '{ name: string; episode: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<[string, any]>'

in below piece of code.

```
let movie = Immutable.Map<string, any>({
   name: "Star Wars",   
   episode: 8
});
```

I don't know Why the above error is showing and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

[string, any] is an array not an Object. Try with:

```
let movie = Immutable.Map(["Star Wars", 7]);
```

Comment: Not working. showing error: Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: {}; }

Comment: let movie = Immutable.Map({["Star Wars"]:{episode: 7 }});